Timing and direction of keyframe animation for SVG
I have an svg that I'm using CSS keyframe on in order to animate it at a certain point and it animates, but the issue is that I need to time out the animations as well as make sure they 'draw' in the right direction. The 'normal' paths on the right need to draw left to right and the 'reverse' paths on the left need to draw right to left (this should end up like the lines, from top to bottom, are drawing center->out.
My issue is that I can't seem to get a delay working on them so that they can draw properly. If I set the reverse keyframe to draw for a negative value of the path length, it draws the path all the way to the right before the right paths even show so that won't work.
How can I make sure the reverse paths draw properly but also time the paths out and have the ability to adjust them as needed?


    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
        var drawingStarted = false;
        var lastScrollTop = 0;
        const normalPath1  = document.querySelector("#footerline1");
        const reversePath1 = document.querySelector("#footerline2");
        const normalPath2  = document.querySelector("#footerline3");
        const reversePath2 = document.querySelector("#footerline4");
        const normalPath3  = document.querySelector("#footerline5");
        const reversePath3 = document.querySelector("#footerline6");
        const normalPath4  = document.querySelector("#footerline7");
        const reversePath4 = document.querySelector("#footerline8");


        window.addEventListener('message', function (event) {

                var footerscrollpercent = event.data.value;
                
                // REMOVE DEBUG
                footerscrollpercent = 1;
                if (!drawingStarted && footerscrollpercent > 0.9) {
                    // Function to add class with delay
                    const addClassWithDelay = (element, className, delay) => {
                        setTimeout(() => {
                            element.classList.add(className);
                        }, delay);
                    };

                    // Add classes with delay
                    addClassWithDelay(normalPath1, 'path-test', 5000);
                    addClassWithDelay(reversePath1, 'path-test-reverse', 2000); // Delay of 5ms
                    addClassWithDelay(normalPath2, 'path-test', 0);
                    addClassWithDelay(reversePath2, 'path-test-reverse', 5); // Delay of 5ms
                    addClassWithDelay(normalPath3, 'path-test', 0);
                    addClassWithDelay(reversePath3, 'path-test-reverse', 5); // Delay of 5ms
                    addClassWithDelay(normalPath4, 'path-test', 0);
                    addClassWithDelay(reversePath4, 'path-test-reverse', 5); // Delay of 5ms
                }

            // }
        });
    });
.path-test {
    stroke-dasharray: 1000;
    stroke-dashoffset: 1000;
    animation: dash 5s linear forwards;
}

@keyframes dash {
    from {
            stroke-dashoffset: 1000;
            /* Start with full dash length */
        }
    to {
        stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    }
}

.path-test-reverse {
    stroke-dasharray: 1000;
    stroke-dashoffset: 1000;
    /* Start with the dash fully visible */
    animation: reverse-dash 5s linear forwards;
    /* Use the reverse-dash animation */
}

@keyframes reverse-dash {
    from {
        stroke-dashoffset: -10;
        /* Start with full dash length */
    }

    to {
        stroke-dashoffset: 0;
        /* Gradually offset the dash to 0 */
    }
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg viewBox="0 0 758.57 337.81">
                <defs>
                    <style>
                        .complexfooter-1 {
                            stroke-width: 12.67px;
                        }
                        .complexfooter-1,
                        .complexfooter-2 {
                            fill: none;
                            stroke: #072334;
                            stroke-miterlimit: 10;
                        }
                        .complexfooter-3 {
                            fill: #072334;
                            stroke-width: 0px;
                        }
                        .complexfooter-2 {
                            stroke-linecap: square;
                            stroke-width: 23.8px;
                        }
                    </style>
                </defs>
                <path  id="footerline1" fill="white" stroke="black" stroke-width="4" class="normal-draw complexfooter-2"
                   d="M381.22,12.6c14.3.44,29.45.94,30.7.94l-12.26-1.5c2.36,0,4.95-.3,7.28-.03,2.08.24,3.02,1.17,4.97,1.54,5.7,1.08,12.66-.05,18.47-.05,17.5,0,35,0,52.51,0,19.74,0,39.31,1.02,59.01,1.39,4.79.09,9.24,1.49,14.02,1.54,2.68.03,5.78-.51,8.4.03,3.97.82,8.32,4.68,11.55,6.88,3.74,2.54,6.2,5.18,9.38,8.36,4.39,4.39,9.92,7.61,13.85,12.46,1.65,2.04,2.36,3.74,2.94,6.21,1.52,6.39,5.13,11.72,8.74,17.24,3.01,4.6,5.11,9.51,7.8,14.28,2.67,4.74,6.14,8.8,8.66,13.65,3.61,6.95,8.33,12.29,13.02,18.55,5.73,7.65,10.65,15.86,16.39,23.5,5.34,7.11,8.98,15.31,13.71,22.84,4.31,6.86,8.91,13.66,13.02,20.64s7.07,14.29,11.67,20.55c3.72,5.06,8.81,9.82,13.07,14.48,4.52,4.93,7.99,10.11,11.58,15.77,3.8,6,8.11,11.53,11.65,17.71,4.28,7.47,8.57,14.94,12.61,22.54,2.29,4.3,2.69,12.16,2.7,17.09" />
                <path  id="footerline2" fill="white" stroke="black" stroke-width="4" class=" reverse-draw complexfooter-2" fill="white" stroke="black" stroke-width="4"
                    d="M11.91,286.97c0-4.93,4.27-10.56,6.56-14.86,4.05-7.6,8.34-15.07,12.61-22.54,3.53-6.18,7.84-11.71,11.65-17.71,3.59-5.66,7.06-10.83,11.58-15.77,4.27-4.66,9.36-9.41,13.07-14.48,4.6-6.26,7.74-13.89,11.67-20.55,4.11-6.98,8.71-13.78,13.02-20.64,4.73-7.53,8.37-15.73,13.71-22.84,5.74-7.64,10.66-15.85,16.39-23.5,4.69-6.26,9.41-11.6,13.02-18.55,2.52-4.85,5.99-8.91,8.66-13.65,2.69-4.77,4.79-9.68,7.8-14.28,3.61-5.52,7.22-10.85,8.74-17.24.59-2.47,1.29-4.17,2.94-6.21,3.93-4.85,9.46-8.07,13.85-12.46,3.18-3.18,5.64-5.82,9.38-8.36,3.23-2.19,7.58-6.06,11.55-6.88,2.62-.54,5.72,0,8.4-.03,4.78-.05,9.23-1.45,14.02-1.54,19.7-.37,39.27-1.39,59.01-1.39,17.5,0,35,0,52.51,0,5.82,0,12.78,1.14,18.47.05,1.95-.37,2.89-1.3,4.97-1.54,1.1-.12,13.08.21,25.73.59" />
                <path  id="footerline3" fill="white" stroke="black" stroke-width="4" class="complexfooter-2"
                    d="M378.92,74.83c25.06.73,53.61,1.51,55.29.43,0,0-4.69,0,0,0,18.33.01,10.99,0,29.32,0,6.86,0,13.71.05,20.57-.03,5.58-.07,10.85,1.48,16.39,1.6,2.97.07,5.96-.4,8.89.21,9.14,1.89,17.67,6.32,23.72,13.25,3.96,4.54,8.26,8.94,12.4,13.32,3.12,3.29,5.41,7.06,8.27,10.57,7.73,9.47,14.82,19.88,21.08,30.45,4.39,7.41,8.11,15.17,12.64,22.49,5.84,9.44,11.28,20.06,18.07,28.81,5.62,7.26,9.76,15.31,14.41,23.26,7.04,12.03,14.28,23.66,22.44,34.98,6.67,9.25,12.92,18.72,19.3,28.16,4.92,7.28,13.14,14.47,11.65,23.91"/>
                <path  id="footerline4" fill="white" stroke="black" stroke-width="4" class="complexfooter-2"
                    d="M89.06,306.23c-1.49-9.43,6.73-16.62,11.65-23.91,6.38-9.44,12.63-18.92,19.3-28.16,8.16-11.31,15.4-22.95,22.44-34.98,4.66-7.96,8.79-16.01,14.41-23.26,6.79-8.76,12.23-19.37,18.07-28.81,4.53-7.32,8.25-15.08,12.64-22.49,6.26-10.57,13.36-20.98,21.08-30.45,2.86-3.51,5.15-7.27,8.27-10.57,4.14-4.38,8.44-8.78,12.4-13.32,6.05-6.94,14.58-11.37,23.72-13.25,2.93-.6,5.92-.14,8.89-.21,5.54-.12,10.81-1.67,16.39-1.6,6.86.09,13.71.03,20.57.03,18.33,0,10.99.01,29.32,0,4.69,0,8.59-.15,12.95-1.17,1.47-.35,18.59.19,37.76.75"/>
                <path  id="footerline5" fill="white" stroke="black" stroke-width="4" class="complexfooter-2"
                    d="M381.22,132.42c-26.3,0-56.96,0-61.4,0-5.9,0-12.03-.49-17.9-.06-3.02.22-5.93,1.32-8.97,1.94-3.3.67-6.74.74-9.47,2.2-2.17,1.16-4.65,3.01-6.58,4.47-5.98,4.52-8.82,11.16-14.19,15.68-2.84,2.38-3.99,5.49-6.03,8.37-2.91,4.11-5.92,8.05-8.47,12.44-5.17,8.9-8.84,18.4-13.47,27.54-2.29,4.52-5.74,8.16-8.16,12.57-5.76,10.51-10.63,22.21-15.13,33.31-3.97,9.8-8.46,18.38-14.44,27.06-4.89,7.1-18.8,34.09-17.53,43.23"/>
                <path  id="footerline6" fill="white" stroke="black" stroke-width="4" class="complexfooter-2"
                    d="M578.38,317.03c1.27-9.14-8.07-31.99-12.96-39.08-5.98-8.67-10.47-17.25-14.44-27.06-4.5-11.1-9.37-22.8-15.13-33.31-2.42-4.41-5.87-8.05-8.16-12.57-4.63-9.14-8.3-18.64-13.47-27.54-2.55-4.39-5.56-8.32-8.47-12.44-2.04-2.88-3.19-5.99-6.03-8.37-5.37-4.51-8.21-11.15-14.19-15.68-1.93-1.46-4.41-3.31-6.58-4.47-2.72-1.45-6.17-1.53-9.47-2.2-3.04-.62-5.95-1.71-8.97-1.94-5.87-.43-12.01.06-17.9.06-7.62,0-15.24,0-22.87,0-3.18,0-19.74,0-38.54,0"/>
                    <path  id="footerline7" fill="white" stroke="black" stroke-width="4" class="complexfooter-2"
                    d="M378.95,195.39c25.94-.12,51.45.02,55.27.02l-15.7-.8c7.82,0,16.53.19,23.52,2.54,3.82,1.29,7.21,2.52,9.5,6.08,2.99,4.66,4.92,10.38,7.56,15.3,5.14,9.56,11.6,17.28,14.57,28,2.37,8.53,6.51,15.55,10.15,23.52,1.27,2.77,1.77,5.83,3.08,8.56,1.39,2.89,3.62,5.66,5.22,8.41,4.96,8.54,7.97,28.36,7.6,38.44"/>
                    <path  id="footerline8" fill="white" stroke="black" stroke-width="4" class="complexfooter-2"
                    d="M262.68,324.92c-.37-10.08,2.68-29.36,7.63-37.9,1.6-2.75,3.83-5.52,5.22-8.41,1.31-2.73,1.82-5.79,3.08-8.56,3.64-7.98,7.78-15,10.15-23.52,2.98-10.73,9.44-18.44,14.57-28,2.64-4.92,4.57-10.63,7.56-15.3,2.29-3.57,5.68-4.8,9.5-6.08,3.58-1.21,31.3-1.63,58.54-1.76"/>
            </svg>




Please revise your snippet to show at least some animation. Currently, we don't see anything due to a custom event "message" that's not fired.
